# R: readr: how can I specify a datatype for just one (problematic) column (and not all)

Tags: r, readr

Readr is a great package. But people are lazy to specify data type for each column. (out of 30 for example).

Inspecting the parsing failures may reveal that only one column is the key problem.

See it below

```
fname='c:/q/net/SnomedCT_RF2Release_INT_20160131/Full/Terminology/sct2_Concept_Full_INT_20160131.txt'
> snm<-read_delim(fname,delim='\t')
Warning: 4016 parsing failures.
   row col   expected      actual
528950  id an integer 11000119105
528951  id an integer 11000119105
528952  id an integer 41000119109
528953  id an integer 61000119108
528954  id an integer 81000119104
...... ... .......... ...........
.See problems(...) for more details.
> probs<-problems(snm)
> table(probs$col)

  id 
4016 
>
```

How can I specify the datatype of just one column (in my case column id) in my dataset. (to be character)

```
names(snm)
[1] "id"                 "effectiveTime"      "active"             "moduleId"           "definitionStatusId"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By specifying that column in the `col_types` argument using the `cols` function, the rest are left as they are. For example, to specify the `hp` column as character in `mtcars`, use "c" for character.

```
library(readr)
write_delim(mtcars, path = "test.txt")
test <- read_delim("test.txt", delim = " ", col_types = cols(hp = "c"))
str(test)

Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : int  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : chr  "110" "110" "93" "110" ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : int  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : int  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: int  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: int  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

More information in the `readr` column types vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/vignettes/column-types.html